# Is important to use the setContentView(R.layout.name.xml) in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Is important to use the `setContentView(R.layout.name.xml)` in android?
In the following code, I want to draw a line in `relativeLayout Object` without using the `setContentView(R.layout.name.xml)`. It can compile Successfully. But it stops execution time.

**Draw.java**

```
 class Draw extends View {
Paint paint;

    public Draw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

@Override
    protected  void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
paint.setColor(Color.RED);


canvas.drawLine(10,10,100,100,paint);
super.onDraw(canvas);
}}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Draw draw;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle s){
        super.onCreate(s);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        draw = new Draw(this);
       relativeLayout.addView(draw,200,200);

    }
}
```

Comment: really, is my question bad?

Comment: Why my question is bad?

Comment: No bro..Its not bad..people did not get yours question and they only knows that how to down-vote it..Do not think about those people...Sorry i do not have an idea to give you answer...but i will upvote it...Go ahead. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**setContentView()** in Android must be called in the **onCreate()** method before getting any references to any views in the Activity.

Without setContentView() your activity **won't be inflated** with or assigned a layout.

As a result your app won't start because the start activity has no layout or UI to display.

So, always include a setContentView(), passing the layout as the parameter, in the onCreate() method of your activity.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What method `setContentView` does is not just setting resource of layout, but something more important. If it's a new activity, it will generate the window decor, apply the theme to your activity and so on. So you see, you cannot just dismiss this and replacing it with your code.

Answer (score -1):

try add this code at the end of onCreate method

```
setContentView(relativeLayout);
```